# Windows XP Remote Desktop Connection program

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I am missing the [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) program icon that normally lives in menu *Start* → *Accessories* → *Communication*. I know it's installed though. What is the actual file name for that program?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for

```
mstsc.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to console into the machine, use

```
MSTSC /console
```

or

```
MSTSC /Admin
```

depending on what version of Remote Desktop Connection you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Type `mstsc` in the run prompt (<kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

A Windows update (or SP) moved it to (I believe) just the Accessories folder and it has a new icon.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It could be from Windows XP SP2 to Windows XP SP3 (but I only have one datapoint).

Comment: I can confirm that I have RDC in Windows XP SP2. However, I do remember that it was also a non-default application. It had to be specifically installed by the *Add new components* wizard, using the installation disk.