# Remote Desktop client for Windows XP Home

Tags: windows, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to connect to XP Home PC from XP Pro using Remote Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/46845/how-to-connect-to-xp-home-pc-from-xp-pro-using-remote-desktop)
>   [Windows XP Remote Desktop program](https://superuser.com/questions/42801/windows-xp-remote-desktop-program)

Hi,

I'm looking for a remote desktop client that works in windows xp home edition the same way Windows remote desktop does. this is, without the need to install anything on the server.

is there any tool that does that?

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [How to connect to XP Home PC from XP Pro using Remote Desktop](http://superuser.com/questions/46845/how-to-connect-to-xp-home-pc-from-xp-pro-using-remote-desktop). This same question was already asked and closed once today.

Comment: Sorry, after re-reading, I see that you are looking for a client, not a server. The Remote Desktop _client_ is already built into windows.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP Home doesn't contain the server feature natively. A client is available:

From http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/tools/rdclientdl.mspx:

> The Remote Desktop Connection software
>   is pre-installed with Windows XP. To
>   run it, click Start, click All
>   Programs, click Accessories, click
>   Communications, and then click Remote
>   Desktop Connection. This software
>   package can also be found on the
>   Windows XP Professional and Windows XP
>   Home Edition product CDs and can be
>   installed on any supported Windows
>   platform. To install from the CD,
>   insert the disc into the target
>   machine's CD-ROM drive, select Perform
>   Additional Tasks, and then click
>   Install Remote Desktop Connection.

If you're looking for a replacement that requires no additional installation on the server side, I'm not sure any exists. I do know of [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com). It has a portable version that requires no installation and runs from a single .exe file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the link you said apparently only applies to Windows 95, 98, 98SE, Me, NT 4.0, or 2000, but not XP Home?

Comment: also, apparently you can only connect to XP Professional Computers. I need to connect to web servers so I dont think that this will work? any other ideas?

Comment: @xxuser that's because the page is meant for that, it's the bottom note I was interested in... It tells us that the client should be available for Windows XP (No matter which version) From the quote: "To run it, click `Start`, click `All Programs`, click `Accessories`, click `Communications`, and then click `Remote Desktop Connection`."

Comment: @xxuser you should be able to connect to any RDP server from this... also other servers, not just XP Pro machines. However, it is true that from the Windows XP versions (Home & Pro), only Pro has the RDP server feature. They both have client feature though.

Comment: so basically the RDC tool for windows xp home works just as well as the windows xp pro or windows 7 one? I was under the impression that the biggest "problem" with windows xp home was the lack of the remote desktop tool...

Comment: @xxuser, what is lacking on XP Home is the server software (though "Remote Assistence" effectively uses that same server software, but only runs by inviting folks). The **client** you're looking for is definitely included in XP Home. Just try!

Comment: @xxuser As far as I know, yes, it should work just as well... If it isn't available, the software package can also be found on the Windows XP Professional and Windows XP Home Edition product CDs and can be installed on any supported Windows platform. To install from the CD, insert the disc into the target machine's CD-ROM drive, select Perform Additional Tasks, and then click Install Remote Desktop Connection.